# Azure Application Insight Monitor web Traffic

Tags: azure, google-analytics, analytics, azure-application-insights

Like google analytics is there any way i can monitor web traffic like Organic Traffic,Referral Traffic in application insight analytics section

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET website,you can create a TelemetryInitializer to add the UrlReferrer to requests.

[Filtering and preprocessing telemetry in the Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer)

Also to prepare chart you can do the following:-

1. You can use Metrics Explorer to create a chart,
   Select "Server requests" under Metrics.
   Turn on "Show advanced settings"
   And then find Referrer under "Group by".
2. You can search custom properties using the Analytics tool
   For example:

requests
| extend referrer = tostring(customDimensions.Referrer)

Also you can put a script tag code like below for enabling traffic

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(a){
         function b(a){c[a]=function(){var b=arguments;c.queue.push(function(){c[a].apply(c,b)})}}var c={config:a},d=document,e=window;setTimeout(function(){var b=d.createElement("script");b.src=a.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js",d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(b)});try{c.cookie=d.cookie}catch(a){}c.queue=[];for(var f=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"];f.length;)b("track"+f.pop());if(b("setAuthenticatedUserContext"),b("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"),b("startTrackEvent"),b("stopTrackEvent"),b("startTrackPage"),b("stopTrackPage"),b("flush"),!a.disableExceptionTracking){f="onerror",b("_"+f);var g=e[f];e[f]=function(a,b,d,e,h){var i=g&&g(a,b,d,e,h);return!0!==i&&c["_"+f](a,b,d,e,h),i}}return c
     }({
         instrumentationKey: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
     });

     window.appInsights=appInsights,appInsights.queue&&0===appInsights.queue.length&&appInsights.trackPageView();
</script>
```

Where Instrumentation key is your application insight instrumentation key.

Comment: Where i can find "Show advanced settings"  in metrics explorer